# If the set $B=\{f(x) : x\in A\}$ has supremum and $C=\{k+f(x): x\in A\}$, then what is $\sup C$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> If the set $B=\{f(x) : x\in A\}$ has supremum and $C=\{k+f(x): x\in A\}$, then what is $\sup C$?

Since $C$ is not an empty set and $f(x)\le  \sup(B) ⇒ k+f(x)\le k+\sup(B)$.
So $C$ is bounded above. Thus, $\sup(C)\le k+\sup(B)$ 
If $\sup(C)\ge k+\sup(B)$ is true, I can conclude $\sup(C)=k+\sup(B)$.
But I don't know how to show $\sup(C)\ge k+\sup(B)$.

Comment: I reformatted the formulas; see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

- $\sup(C) \geq k + \sup (B)$ is equivalent with $\sup (C) - k \geq \sup (B)$.
- Given that $\sup (C)$ is an (in fact, the smallest) upper bound on $C$, can you show that $\sup (C) - k$ is an upper bound on $B$?
- Since $\sup(B)$ is its *smallest* upper bound, you'd automatically have the inequality $\sup (C) - k \geq \sup (B)$.

Comment: Thanks. But, Should I show sup(C)-k is an upper bound on B using infinitesimal principle?

Comment: It's even easier than that. We want to show that $\sup(C) - k$ is an upper bound on $B$. So let $b \in B$. Then $k + b \in C$ and consequently $k + b \leq \sup (C)$. This means that $b \leq \sup (C) - k$. Since $b \in B$ was arbitrary, $\sup (C) - k$ is an upper bound on $B$.